# declaration of variables in R

Tags: r

I have a problem of using a variable in R Studio. My code is as following. "child_birth" is a vector composed of 49703 strings that indicates some information about the birth of childre. What I did here is to tell whether the last 7 characters in each element of the vector is "at home". So I used a for loop and an if statement. if it is "at home", then the corresponding element in vector "GetValue" will be TRUE.

```
forloop <- (1:49703)
for (i in forloop){
  temp <- child_birth[i]
  if (substr(temp, nchar(temp)-6, nchar(temp)) == "at home" ) {
    GetValue[i] = TRUE
  }
  else{ GetValue[i] = FALSE }
}
```

I googled it to make sure that in R I don't need to do a predecalration before using a variable. but when I ran the code above, I got the error information:" Error: object 'GetValue' not found". So what's the problem with it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetValue[i]` only makes sense if `GetValue` (and `i`) exist. Compare: `x+i` only makes sense if `x` and `i` exist, which has nothing to do with whether or not `x` and `i` must be declared before being used.

In this case, you need to define `GetValue` before the loop. I recommend

```
GetValue <- logical(length(child_birth))
```

so as to allocate enough space. In this case, you could drop the `else` clause completely since the default logical value is `FALSE`.

I also recommend dropping the variable `forloop` and using

```
for(i in seq_along(child_birth))
```

Why hard-wire in the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) 49703? Such numbers are subject to change. If you put them explicitly in the code, you are setting yourself up for future bugs.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your solution! but I still have a question, do I on earth need to pre declaration variables? For example in the above code, I didn't declare "i" but i can use it in the for loop. However I can't use "GetValue" without declaration. I'm abit confused now.

Comment: @kaiyuwei  You aren't declaring `GetValue` here -- you are creating it by assignment. The for loop construct does the job of creating the counter variable `i`. R is closer to Python than it is to C or Java. It isn't a compiled language (so the notion of declaring would be somewhat unmotivated) but a variable still needs to be created before it is used. In `GetValue <- logical(length(child_birth))` the right hand side creates a vector. Assigning that vector to `GetValue` is what creates the variable.